# Spring - PostMapping Without Redirecting

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc

I have been working on this app which simulates a shopping cart to learn Spring framework. When I the user clicks "Add Item" I want to stay on the same site, create a product object and add it to the cart object in the background(Optionally display a message on the site?). And when the user is done adding and clicks "Generate Receipt"
I want to display another page with all their carts content and total price. The second part about redirecting to a new page and displaying all their cart is fine but I could not figure out how to stay on the same page when clicked on "Add Item" and displaying an "Item Added" kind of message on the site. How could I do this.

Site looks like this :

[image]

Here is my Spring Application File :

```
package spring.shoppingcart;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.sql.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class SpringShoppingApplication {

    private static ProductDb productDb = new ProductDb();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringShoppingApplication.class, args);
    }

    @PostMapping("/generateReceipt")
    public static String generateReceipt() {
        return "Your Receipt : ";
    }

    @PostMapping("/addToCart")
    public static String addToCart(
            @RequestParam(value = "productName", defaultValue = "") String productName,
            @RequestParam(value = "productQuantity", defaultValue = "") String productQuantity
    ) {
        if (productDb.getProduct(productName) == null) {
            return "No Such Product : " + productName;
        } else if (!isInteger(productQuantity)) {
            return "Quantity Should Be An Integer : " + productQuantity;
        }else{
            return "Product Name : " + productDb.getProduct(productName).name() + " Product Quantity : " + productQuantity;
        }
    }

    public static boolean isInteger(String str) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(str);
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }


}
```

And here is my HTML file :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Shopping Cart</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"/>
</head>
<body>
<style>
    html {
        color: whitesmoke;
        background-color: steelblue;
    }

    #content {
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: center;
    }

    #db {
        text-align: center;
        background-color: cornflowerblue;
    }

    #tab {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
</style>

<div id="content">
    <form method="post">
        Product Name :<br><br>
        <input type="text" name="productName">
        <br><br>
        Product Quantity :<br><br>
        <input type="text" name="productQuantity">
        <br><br>
        <button type="submit" formaction="/addToCart">Add to Cart</button>
        <button type="submit" formaction="/generateReceipt">Generate Receipt</button>
    </form>
</div>

<br><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use some jQuery Ajax to do POST requests for this purpose. You would have something like this in a someScriptName.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#my-form").submit(function (event) {
        var productData = {}
        productData["productName"] = $("#productNameId").val();
        productData["productQuantity"] = $("#productQuantityId").val();

        $("#success-msg").hide();
        $("#error-msg").hide();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: "/addToCart",
            data: JSON.stringify(productData),
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            timeout: 60000,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#success-msg").show();
            },
            error: function (e) {
                $("#error-msg").show();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

You would have to include this .js as part of your HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/someScriptName.js"></script>
```

Comment: So I will use this file to get the inputs, not the forms in html?

Comment: You would still have a form for adding - you can add event.preventDefault(); to the javascript to prevent the default form submission action. You can create another form to do a POST for generating the receipt

Comment: Thank you, I figured out making add button not redirect and the generate receipt redirect. How can I display the succes and error messages tho?

Comment: You can create elements in HTML that are display: none by default. On success, you can utilize the success function like this: $("#success-msg").show();. Same with the error message - you just have to set the proper IDs for those elements.

Comment: And how can I use the elements productName and productQuantity in the Java class to create objects?

Comment: Depends on how you create an object. If you have a constructor for that object that accepts name and quantity - great, just create it like Product product = new Product(productName, productQuantity). Though usually you would have an empty constructor and setters, so you would create a Product product = new Product(); and call product.setName(productName) and product.setQuantity(productQuantity) before persisting it to the database or doing whatever you need to do here.

Comment: I have both an empty constructor and a constructor with elements, but I can not yet add to the list of receipt entries in the spring application class. Here is updated my html file : https://pastebin.pl/view/cf317e53 , here is my updated spring app class : https://pastebin.pl/view/a881f622